# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'utils') bootstrap-table-sticky-header.js:1648

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, bootstrap-5, bootstrap-table

I have a bootstrap-table that I am trying to implement bootstrap-table-sticky-header in, but I am getting the following error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'utils') bootstrap-table-sticky-header.js:1648

I am using bootstrap-table 1.21.2 and bootstrap 5.2.3

Below is my code:

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Assets By Associate";
}

<div id="divPageContainer">
    <div id="toolbar">
        <select class="form-control">
            <option value="">Export Page</option>
            <option value="all">Export All</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div id="divAssetesByAssociate" class="table-responsive">
        <table id="tblAssetesByAssociate"
               class="table-condensed table-striped"
               
               data-toggle="table"
               data-search="true"
               data-sort-name="AssetesByAssociateKey"
               data-sort-order="asc"
               data-show-columns="true"
               data-advanced-search="true"
               data-id-table="advancedTable"
               data-show-multi-sort="true"
               data-show-export="true"
               data-toolbar="#toolbar"
               data-click-to-select="true"
               data-cookie="true"
               data-pagination="true"
               data-show-jump-to="true"
               data-url="/AssetsByAssociates/GetAssetsByAssociateData"
               data-cookie-id-table="tblAssetesByAssociateID"
               data-page-size="10"
               data-page-list="[10, 25, 50, 100, All]"
               data-sticky-header="true">
            <thead>
                <tr style="background-color: #FFFFFF;">
                    <th data-field="Associate_Name" data-visible="true" data-searchable="true" data-sortable="true">Associate Name</th>
                    <th data-field="Laptop_Model" data-visible="true" data-searchable="true" data-sortable="true">Laptop Model</th>
                    <th data-field="Laptop_SN" data-visible="true" data-searchable="true" data-sortable="true">Laptop SN</th>
                    <th data-field="Lan_Mac_address" data-visible="true" data-searchable="true" data-sortable="true">LAN MAC Address</th>
                    <th data-field="WLaN_Mac_address" data-visible="true" data-searchable="true" data-sortable="true">WLaN Mac address</th>
                    <th data-field="Montior_1_Input" data-visible="true" data-searchable="true" data-sortable="true">Montior 1 Input</th>
                    <th data-field="Montior_1_SN" data-visible="true" data-searchable="true" data-sortable="true">Montior 1 SN</th>
                    <th data-field="Montior_2_Input" data-visible="true" data-searchable="true" data-sortable="true">Montior 2 Input</th>
                    <th data-field="Montior_2_SN" data-visible="true" data-searchable="true" data-sortable="true">Montior 2 SN</th>
                    <th data-field="Docking_Station_SN" data-visible="true" data-searchable="true" data-sortable="true">Docking Station SN</th>
                    <th data-field="Printer_PN" data-visible="true" data-searchable="true" data-sortable="true">Printer PN</th>
                    <th data-field="Printer_SN" data-visible="true" data-searchable="true" data-sortable="true">Printer SN</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>

@section scripts{
    <link href="~/lib/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="~/lib/bootstrap-table/bootstrap-table.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="~/lib/bootstrap-table/extensions/page-jump-to/bootstrap-table-page-jump-to.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="~/lib/bootstrap-table/extensions/filter-control/bootstrap-table-filter-control.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="~/lib/bootstrap-table/extensions/sticky-header/bootstrap-table-sticky-header.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="~/lib/bootstrap-table/bootstrap-table.js" type="module"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/bootstrap-table/extensions/toolbar/bootstrap-table-toolbar.js" type="module"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/bootstrap-table/extensions/multiple-sort/bootstrap-table-multiple-sort.js" type="module"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/bootstrap-table/extensions/export/bootstrap-table-export.js" type="module"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/bootstrap-table/extensions/cookie/bootstrap-table-cookie.js" type="module"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/bootstrap-table/extensions/page-jump-to/bootstrap-table-page-jump-to.js" type="module"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/bootstrap-table/tableExport.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/bootstrap-table/extensions/sticky-header/bootstrap-table-sticky-header.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
        #divAssetesByAssociate {
            margin-bottom: 150px;
        }

        #divPageContainer {
            width: 95%;
            margin: auto;
        }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(function () {
            ToolbarInit();
        });

        function ToolbarInit() {
            $('#toolbar').find('select').change(function () {
                $('#tblAssetesByAssociate').bootstrapTable('destroy').bootstrapTable({
                    exportDataType: $(this).val(),
                    exportTypes: ['json', 'xml', 'csv', 'txt', 'sql', 'excel']
                })
            }).trigger('change');
        }
    </script>
}
```

My table works as expected except for the sticky header. I have tried changing the order of the load of the .css and the scripts to no avail.

Comment: Have you found a solution for that ?